# Autodesk APS viewer: Sheets & Views

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Currently, I am working on an application that requires viewing multiple PDF/2D sheets. I have implemented the use of `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` in my application as shown in the image below.

However, my college has requested a change in the application's style to resemble the BIM360 Sheets & Views tab, as depicted in the image below, is there a way to do that.

Or, can I use `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` to be automatically activated and positioned in the left corner every time the viewer.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` does not support this kind of customization, unfortunately. You *could* resize and reposition the actual `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Panel` holding the DocumentBrowser content to turn it into a sidebar but that's a bit too hacky IMHO.

If you want a look&feel similar to that of BIM360, I'd suggest that you simply build it yourself as vanilla HTML. You could look at the [DocumentBrowser source code](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/DocumentBrowser/DocumentBrowser.js) (specifically the `ThumbnailListView` class) for reference.